# How to custom Buglife sdk in Android?

Tags: android, external, libraries

I got some problems using buglife sdk [buglife](https://github.com/Buglife), I understand how to add some features, call the functions, etc., but my main problem its that in the "Report a bug" view I need to change the title from "**Report a bug**" to something else, also I need to change the default hint of the editText from "**What happened**" to anything else as shown in the picture below. I can't found any information of how to achieve this and its a bit difficult to me to make this happend.

[Image of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFZYA.png)

Pd. I really like this mobile bug reporting because its very easy to integrate with my existing app but also if I can't change this attributes (I think those attributes could be changed but can't fin a way how to do it...) I can't use this awesome sdk because those minor 'details' that the view gives

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Given that the project is open-source you didn't at least try to search for the strings/text you want to change and change them rather than use the pre-built gradle module.

Comment: I did, and found the strings, but I don't know how to download the project and import it >with the strings changed< to my current project... Any help?

Comment: Found the solution (but at the first try it didn't work and I don't know why), I just go to the github proyect found the var name of the title string I want to change and copy it > then goes to my values/string xml inside my project, paste the variable and change its text and it works....
At fist I try it and it didn't work so I figure it just doesn't work like that... but now that I test it again its working...